# only one setter of the syle of a wpf datagrid is assigned. how to enable other setter?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, styles

i have added 2 setters to a style and assigned that style to a wpf datagridtemplatecolumn cell style.
but one of them is assigned. another one is not assigned. any one know how to solve this?

```
 Style st = new Style();
 Setter sett2 = new Setter
 {
     Property = TextBox.BackgroundProperty,
     Value = Brushes.Yellow
 };
 Setter sett = new Setter
 {
     Property = TextBox.IsEnabledProperty,
     Value = false
 };
 st.Setters.Add(sett);
 st.Setters.Add(sett2);
 col.CellStyle = st;
```

Isenabled property is set false. but colur is still gray.

Comment: Question: why do you create this style in code instead of defining it in XAML?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce this (i.e. the background indeed becomes yellow).

If you explicitly set the background on the TextBox/TextBlock inside the template this style will not affect it due to [dependency property value precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). There could be other causes but there is not enough context to go by, for me at least.